# Core-Plot [Title positioning for CPTAxis Along The Y-Axis]

Tags: ios8, core-plot, ios7.1

I am working on a bar chart and trying to set up the label on the Y-Axis.
The code for this follows.

```
CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axisSet.yAxis.title = @"Workouts";
axisSet.yAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = -60.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
```

While testing this I noticed two cases:

1) y-value is non-zero: In this scenario my CPTAxis title is centered between the max and min
                        y values that are plotted which looks great.

2) y-value is zero: In this scenario my CPTAxis title is centered at y=0, which looks funny.

Is there a property I can set, so that when the y-value is zero, my CPTAxis title is centered
at the midpoint of my view instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `titleLocation` to position the center of the axis title anywhere you want. The default (`NAN`) automatically centers the title along the axis.